# Encode jwt with a p12 file, or a .key extracted from said p12

Tags: python, jwt, pkcs#12, pyjwt

I have a `my_key.p12` file, password-protected. I extracted the key with

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my_key.p12 -out my_key.key -nocerts -nodes -passin pass:<password>
```

Now I'm trying to sign a JWT with python using pyjwt, but no matter what I try I get errors.

A simple

```py
private_key_file = Path(f"my_key.key")
encoded = jwt.encode({"some": "payload"}, private_key_file.read_bytes(), algorithm="RS256")
```

returns an exception (see https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/issues/717). Note that this example is taken straight out of the docs.

Does anyone know how exactly someone is  supposed to encode a JWT in python with a p12 file, or in any case using the algorithm RS256, if I must convert the p12 file to an intermediate key type?